# Checking for nullable lazy value

Tags: c#

If I have a Lazy value defined such as

```
Lazy<MyObject> _lazyObject = new Lazy<MyObject>();
```

If I want to check the value of this isn't null, before I call a method, which option should I do?

```
if (_lazyObject.IsValueCreated && _lazyObject.Value.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    return false;
} 

return _lazyObject.Value.MyMethod();
```

or

```
return _lazyObject?.Value?.MyMethod() ?? false;
```

I am preferring the second option because I think it accounts for the slight possibility that the Lazy object may become null between when it gets a handle, and when it makes the call. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: `Dispose` doesn't mean an object is `null`.

Comment: I have reworded the question to be clearer. I am looking for null, not disposal. Something setting it to null, in another thread.

Comment: Are you expecting `_lazyObject` to be `null`, or `_lazyObject.Value` to be null? The idea of `Lazy<>` is you don't have to do any checking for null before using it.

Comment: Just _lazyObject.Value, but is there any harm in checking _lazyObject as well?

Comment: Check your code first if your condition succeed or not.."_lazyObject.IsValueCreated && _lazyObject.Value.Handle == IntPtr.Zero"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question it is unclear what the problem is you're actually trying to solve.  `_lazyObject.Value` should never be null unless you're providing a factory into the constructor that returns null.

For example

```
var lazy = new Lazy<string>(() => null);

var isNull = lazy.Value == null; // isNull is true
```

If `Lazy<>` is being used correctly you shouldn't need to check for null, you just use the value and whatever thread gets there first creates the value. Checking `IsValueCreated` will tell you if the value has been created yet, but I don't know why you would need to know this.

Generally the field/property holding the `Lazy<>` should be made `readonly` as you don't want to have multiple instances.